# ¿Como mandar registros de mi base de datos SQLite de mi móvil, a la base de datos (MYSQL) de mi computadora de escritorio con DELPHI 10.2?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

Esta aplicación debe ser desarrollada en delphi 10.2 Tokyo.
Les explico, tengo  una base de datos MySQL en mi computadora de escritorio, la cual cuenta con una simple tabla llamada animales, y tiene 2 campos 'nombre' y 'tipo', a su vez tengo la misma base de datos dentro de mi Teléfono donde mediante a una App que realice en delphi 10.2 puedo agregar animales y son guardados en la base de datos de mi teléfono.
Lo que quiero saber es como puedo (mediante los datos móviles de mi celular) agregar a la base de datos de mi computadora de escritorio, los nuevos registros que vaya agregando a la base de datos de mi teléfono celular.
Dicho de otra manera quiero que cuando agregue un nuevo animal por medio de mi teléfono también se agregue en la base de datos de mi computador, es posible y como podría llevar a cabo este proyecto, espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Voto el cierre de la pregunta por no tratarse de una pregunta para resolver un problema en concreto, si no que solicita opiniones acerca de cómo solucionar un problema común. En mi opinión deberías: a) La aplicación Android solicite la modificación al servidor MySQL de manera directa (si el servidor está expuesto públicamente). b) Hagas uso de un sistema de colas de mensajes externo (como un RabbitMQ, Amazon SQS, Google Cloud Pub/Sub, etc) para enviar las modificaciones y que tu cliente en Delphi las obtenga y actualice en el servidor MySQL. c) (cont.).

Comment: c) Instalar una segunda aplicación que tenga acceso a la base de datos sqlite y que sea la encargada de enviar las modificaciones o de escuchar conexiones externas para comunicar los cambios... Habría muchas más soluciones, pero todo depende de la visibilidad entre dispositivos, de los recursos y servidores que puedas instalar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para esta cuestión tienes 2 problemas a resolver o plantearte. Pero para darte respuestas concretas deberías dar más dartos de esos equipos.

1. Comunicaciones
2. Sincronización de datos

El primero es la **comunicación** entre ambos equipos. Tu equipo (computadora de escritorio) suele estar detrás de un router y lo normal es que tenga una **IP dinámica** (si no es así deberías decirlo). Con esta configuración no puedes conectarlos directamente, simplemente porque tu computadora de escritorio no tiene siempre la misma IP a la que conectarse.

Si esto es así, a veces se utiliza un elemento intermedio al que ambos puedan conectarse, por ejempo un **FTP**/**WebServer**, donde uno deja ficheros y otro los lee. Pero estas opciones no suelen ser óptimas.

Si tu equipo SI tiene **IP fija**, el tema cambia y se abren otras posibilidades.

Si ambos equipos están en la misma red (LAN) lo anterior dicho cambia.

Si ambos equipos están cerca (por ejemplo dentro de la misma oficina), se pueden conectar utilizando **Tethering** (Wifi o Bluetooth).

Como ves, hay muchas opciones, pero das poco información y poco concreta para poder ayudarte más.

El segundo tema, el de la sincronización, no tiene sentido abordarlo hasta que no tengas claro el primero.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, la idea es que pueda utilizar mis datos movil y sincronizar la base de datos de mi celular, y a la ver poder ingresar registros a mi computadora desde cualquier otra red, mi computadora tiene IP Dinamica, pero ya la voy a establecer como dinamica, tambien se que tengo que abrir puertos del modem pero no se como hacerlo y que me tendria que conectar a mi ip dinamica.

Comment: @Kenneth. Si tu computadora va a tenber IP fija, puedes conectar directamente a ella. No directamente a la Base de Datos (no es recomendable por temas de seguridad, aunque se puede hacer), pero sí puedes implemenetar otras soluciones como esta (http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/15-aplicacion-de-acceso-a-datos-introduccion/) para poder consultar y actualizar la Base de Datos desde un móvil.